# Sentry - How to pass full url with exception?

Tags: javascript, sentry

I use Sentry to track javascript errors on client.

In sentry dashboard I see not full url (no query part).
How to pass full url?

Example

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify the question? Which URL? Where do you pass that URL?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer updated quiestion

Comment: Depending on the SDK you can scroll down below the traceback to see more request data

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. In Sentry UI full URL is at the bottom (see image)
2. If you need to forward it to slack or other integrations where you can only send tags you will need to add a custom tag like `full-url` (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/enriching-events/tags/)

[image: In their UI full URL is at the bottom]